# Gradle: Could Not Fetch Model of Type 'EclipseProject'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin

This is the first time I'm using Gradle, and I'm fairly new to Java as well. I'm using Eclipse Neon, Gradle 3.4 and JDK 1.8.

When attempting to set up a Gradle application, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method mainClassName() for arguments [com.mycompany.app.MyMapApp] on task ':run' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.
```

It's complaining about line 25 in my build.gradle file, which is:

```
run { mainClassName 'com.mycompany.app.MyMapApp'}
```

I'm not sure if the mainClassName I'm specifying should be different, or if there's something wrong with my version of Gradle?

Has anyone run into this themselves, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing equal sign (`=`) between `mainClassName` and `'com.mycompany.app.MyMapApp'`. You can take `mainClassName 'com.mycompany.app.MyMapApp'` outside of the `run { ... }` block.

Simple, complete example of your build.gradle can look like following

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.app.MyMapApp'
```

Comment: This seems to make it build, but I still have to test it. Quick question, is the run{ } (empty or not) even needed then?

Comment: I edited the answer.  `run { ... }` is not needed. In fact, I do not see it even in the docu https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html .